# How to reduce footer size in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

is there a way to decrease the footer height? I have been playing with the style.css, but did not make it. I would need the footer height as small as possible. Can anyone help?
My client is asking he want full width slider in home page without scroll bar and he is asking footer is also visible in home page like sticky footer without scroll. I tried but its not working. please save me out from this.

website is in wordpress

This is my website url: http://f9interiors.com/

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: "My client is asking he want full width slider in home page"
he is looking for all devices or specific resolution ??

Comment: @Jay If your client want a "Responsive Website", your website is not responsive! I think he want for all device... You should use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Thank You but Where Can i add media queries in wordpress websites ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.copyright-wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(13, 9, 0, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    line-height: 15px
}

.copyright-wrapper .container{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: still it is little bit bigger. Please reduce the size.

Comment: Hi sir, please help me

Comment: Sorry , No other code helped, I consulted a friend with mine to give a proper solution, unfortunately no improved code. Have to wait for another community member.

Answer (score 1):

Update following css. you change padding as per your requirement.

```
.copyright-wrapper {
   background-color: rgba(13, 9, 0, 0.4);
   position: relative;
   padding: 5px 0;
}
.copyright-wrapper .container{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If i kept 5px then alignment is gone. the footer content displayed at right side. I customized a lot. please save me

Comment: You can see the footer in this website http://fortune9.in/. I want like that.

Comment: Add this css too -- .copyright-wrapper .container{display: inline-block;}

Comment: i added to footer. but its not looking good. Please customize a little bit. I am poor at CSS

Comment: i check on site -- http://fortune9.in/ and it seems good please let me know whats your issue.

Comment: Issue is not in fortune9.in .I want footer like this for my website  f9interiors.com

Comment: look like you have resolved the issue -- can you please accept this answer if its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

apply that css

```
section#home_slider {
height: calc(100vh - 65px);
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @vasanthamareddy but i can see a scrollbar on your website :D

Comment: My website does not have responsive. It is not good in all devices. I don't know why. I want to be dispaly only image in home page without any scroll bar. I tried a lot. I don't know what are the image pixels to presenting full width image in home page. It does not good looking in mobile view as well as desktop view. My client requirement is displaying image in home without scroll and it will be good at all devices. please guide me 

http://f9interiors.com/

Thanks in Advance